# Geopandas Connect Points

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I am trying to create a basic origin/destination map of lines. My data has this structure:

```
ID lon_origin  lat_origin  lon_destination  lat_destination
0  -116.284    43.617      -116.304         43.608
1  -116.291    43.610      -116.304         43.608
```

Any ideas on how to connect the origins & destinations? I have tried zipping them but I can't get geopandas to recognize two geometry columns at once.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Something like the .drawgreatcircle [tool](https://python-graph-gallery.com/300-draw-a-connection-line/) iterrated over each row in the dataframe. When I try that, I get `TypeError: input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar`.

Comment: Solved the TypeError problem for a single row by calling .values after each column name. Now iterating is giving me the following:
`for index, row in df.iterrows():
    m.drawgreatcircle(df['lon_orig'].values,df['lat_orig'].values,df['lon_dest'].values,df['lat_dest'].values, linewidth=2, color='orange')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to calculate the distance, here is one solution :

```
from geopy.distance import lonlat, distance
data = """
  id      lon_origin  lat_origin  lon_destination  lat_destination
   0    -116.284    43.617      -116.304         43.608
   1    -116.291    43.610      -116.304         43.608
    """
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['KM'] = df.apply(
    (lambda row:distance(lonlat(row['lon_origin'], row['lat_origin']),
                         lonlat(row['lon_destination'], row['lat_destination'])).km), axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   id  lon_origin  lat_origin  lon_destination  lat_destination       KM
0   0    -116.284      43.617         -116.304           43.608  1.89910
1   1    -116.291      43.610         -116.304           43.608  1.07277
```

if you want to use Miles, just change the metric:

```
df['MILES'] = df.apply(
    (lambda row:distance(lonlat(row['lon_origin'], row['lat_origin']),
                         lonlat(row['lon_destination'], row['lat_destination'])).miles), axis=1)

   id  lon_origin  lat_origin  lon_destination  lat_destination     MILES
0   0    -116.284      43.617         -116.304           43.608  1.180046
1   1    -116.291      43.610         -116.304           43.608  0.666588
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up forgoing the drawgreatcircle function because it wouldn't be very great or circular at the scale I was using. plt.plot did what I was after:
[Code & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XRZN.png)